# PHP/MySQL upload image with comment and print it

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing a website, really really simple btw that its pretty much done, but some problems got me! here are the 3 pages:

index.php http://pastebin.com/whQfhPEy 
admin.php http://pastebin.com/pQCsphCa 
upload.php:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxx", "xxxx");
mysql_select_db("xxxx");

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

index.php prints messages / images uploaded via admin.php 
admin.php is for submiting data / images so that way can be shown on index.php 
upload.php is called when the submit button is pressed on admin.php

Question: I need to modify upload.php to somehow put an ID on every uploaded image so it can be printed on index.php using its ID, How should it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

question 1 : The main problem is that on admin.php after filling the forms and clicking "submit" it won't Insert data into my database table, what am I missing?:

You are sending wrong SQL. Chanage `value` to `values`

Change

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO BlogData ('title', 'category', 'content') VALUE('$title', '$category', '$content')");
```

to

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO BlogData (`title`, `category`, `content`) VALUES('$title', '$category', '$content')");
```

question 2 : I want to add a "image upload" option on the form, how do I do it?
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

question 3 : On index.php all the entries are being "printed", how do I show the image that I've uploaded with the form too?

Fetch the image paths from database and add `<img/>`s for it.

**Also `mysql_` functions are deprecated.
Use `mysqli_` instead.**

Comment: allright, that fixed the "question 1" thanks alot! :) and wow, that was fast!

Comment: Hi @JonathanSmith, if my answer works for you, please mark it as solution.

Comment: @Ghost Yeah I've been told that MySQL is not good and use mysqli instead, but It's an emergency can't do it right now =(, and the ' instead of ` worked...

Comment: @JonathanSmith what do you mean i'm on an emergency right now? its just almost the same as using mysqli. if you're not comfortable in using the object oriented interface it also has that procedural interface much like the mysql counterpart, not much hard to port your code to it. this will just make you vulnerable to sql injections

Comment: @Ghost Really don't know how to migrate to MySQLi, don't even know if my HOST supports it, I'm kinda new to this and I need to finish this asap, I'll learn MySQLi and find new host after this, thats the main reason, I feel bad cuz I know I should, but it will have to wait =/

Comment: @JonathanSmith you don't have to worry about it, most likely its bundled there already, its already out since PHP5. i urge you to start learning it now, as you use a new host, most likely you'll be forced to migrate your codes as it is already deprecated, rewritting the whole code again. anyways, its documented in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php

Comment: @ProgrammingStudent I wanna merge admin.php with upload.php to be only admin.php, so I tried this: http://pastebin.com/g0mvM4Tp but its giving me error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /admin.php on line 57

Comment: Check all curly braces.

Comment: @JonathanSmith you should use something like $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] to get the size of the image, and not the getimagesize function

If you wawnt to check the file size, as to allow only allow file up to a certain size you 
 // Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}


http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: @ProgrammingStudent I did 2 diff forms pastebin.com/pQCsphCa upload now works... now I gonna try to print it :)

Comment: How do I do a sequence ID witch each uploaded image? and then print them by ID?